# Table name in has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with a couple through associations looking for siblings, i.e. records that have the same parent but are not itself.

```rb
class Person
  has_many :siblings, -> { where("being_siblings.id != beings.id") }, through: :beings, source: :self_and_related_beings
  has_many :nice_humans, through: :siblings, source: :human
end
```

My issue is that if I run `person.nice_humans` the join table used by the query is named differently (in this case something like `being_nice_humans`) than when I run `person.siblings` in which case it is called something like `being_siblings`. Is there any way that I can tell rails what to alias the table as or otherwise make this work?

I have tried something like `-> (p) { where.not("beings.id = ?", p.id) }` but I need to use this in an `includes` which is not allowed when I pass the instance in.

Note: My example is based on a real application but I have the names of the associations.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually define an assocation like that since the definition of an assocation is class and not instance level.

While you can use a lambda to add default scoping to an assocation that lambda does not take arguments as there is no way to pass those arguments when joining, including or eager loading an association. `self` inside the lambda is an association proxy and not the record itself so you can't write `->{ where.not(id: self.id) }`.

What you can do is write an instance method:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, optional: :true, 
                      class_name: 'Person'

  has_many :siblings, class_name: 'Person',
                      foreign_key: :parent_id,
                      primary_key: :parent_id
  
  def siblings
    # super is the getter created by the association
    super.where.not(id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
irb(main):001:0> Person.all
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Person id: 1, name: "Odin", parent_id: nil, created_at: "2021-01-05 20:36:23", updated_at: "2021-01-05 20:36:23">, #<Person id: 2, name: "Thor", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2021-01-05 20:37:51", updated_at: "2021-01-05 20:37:51">, #<Person id: 3, name: "Balder", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2021-01-05 20:38:56", updated_at: "2021-01-05 20:38:56">]>
irb(main):002:0> Person.last.siblings
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" ORDER BY "people"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."parent_id" = ? AND "people"."id" != ? LIMIT ?  [["parent_id", 1], ["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Person id: 2, name: "Thor", parent_id: 1, created_at: "2021-01-05 20:37:51", updated_at: "2021-01-05 20:37:51">]>
```

Comment: This is a simplefied example where the parent is just a simple self-referential association. The same principle would apply though if it where  a join table.

Comment: Thank you! Adding an instance method with the `where.not` clause is a really good idea :)

Comment: One thing though is that you might run into a n+1 query issue if you're looping through a series of people and displaying their siblings. You could possibly check if the association is loaded already and use ‘reject’ instead of the query interface in that case.